# split text file to words and count number of occurrence of each words java

Tags: java, split

this my code where is the error ?
I get that each word appear once

```
HashMap<String, WordData> Words = new HashMap<String, WordData>();
try {
    File f1 = new File(Path);
    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(f1, "UTF-8");
    String word, line;
    WordData wordData;
    String[] wordsOfLine;
        while (scan1.hasNext()) {
            line = scan1.nextLine().trim();
            wordsOfLine = line.split("\\s");

            for (int i = 0; i < wordsOfLine.length&&wordsOfLine[i]!=""; i++) {

                word = wordsOfLine[i].trim();
                if (Words.get(word)==null){
                     wordData = new WordData(1, "");
                    Words.put(word, wordData);
                } else {
                    wordData = Words.get(word);
                    wordData.IncFreq();
                    Words.put(word, wordData);
                }
            }
        }
} catch (Exception ex) {

}
```

Comment: This is very dangerous coding: `catch (Exception ex) {}` Never do this, never have an empty catch block. At least print the stack trace within the block.

Comment: What is `WordData`? Are you sure that it is working? Why not simply use an int instead?

Comment: Provides the way you test it and the expected result. Also, as stated, the catch exception with nothing is VERY dangerous

Comment: If the `WordData` is already in the map, you don't need to "put it back". You could simply do `Words.get(word).IncFreq()` (else part). Also you are comparing `String`s with `!=` instead of using `equals` (for condition) which won't work correctly (`!=` should always yield `true`. in this case you can also use `isEmpty()`)

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your code is when adding the word for the first time, you are setting blank value.

```
class WordData {
    public int getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    public void setFrequency(int frequency) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    private int frequency=0;
    private String word;

    public WordData(int frequency, String word) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.word = word;
    }

    public void increaseFrequency(){
        this.frequency =this.frequency+1;
    }
}
```

```
public class NoOfWordsInFile {
    public static void main( String args[]) {
        HashMap<String, WordData> Words = new HashMap<String, WordData>();
        try {
            File f1 = new File(filepath);
            Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(f1, "UTF-8");
            String word, line;
            WordData wordData;
            String[] wordsOfLine;
            while (scan1.hasNext()) {
                line = scan1.nextLine().trim();
                wordsOfLine = line.split("\\s");

                for (int i = 0; i < wordsOfLine.length&&wordsOfLine[i]!=""; i++) {

                    word = wordsOfLine[i].trim();
                    if (Words.get(word)==null){
                        wordData = new WordData(1, word);
                        Words.put(word, wordData);
                    } else {
                        wordData = Words.get(word);
                        wordData.increaseFrequency();
                        Words.put(word, wordData);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (WordData s : Words.values()){
                System.out.println(s.getWord() +": " + s.getFrequency());
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Also please note this code is case sensitive.
You need to take special care to make this case insensitive.

Comment: it give me the same output of my code I the input is file contains this words (it is just test file )this
this and the output was(that your code print it):this: 1
this: 1

Comment: Hey i assume your text is " (it is just test file )this this ".
here ')this' and 'this' are 2 different words.
With my code and your text you should get the output as 
just: 1
is: 1
)this: 1
test: 1
file: 1
(it: 1
this: 1

If you are not getting the output as expected, please debug the code.